# Checkbox triggering on pageload in knockout.js instead of checkbox click

Tags: knockout.js

I have binded multiple checkboxes to a table. Now I want to associate a click event with each checkboxes.

The method that I have assigned in click event of checkbox fires during document ready but does not fire once it is clicked.

Here is my `click` binding:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" 
       data-bind="click:$root.SelectLine(this,ItemNo())"/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/wcv4k/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `bind` if you want to pass multiple parameters to a click handler as described in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_2_accessing_the_event_object_or_passing_more_parameters).

So change your click binding to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" 
       data-bind="click: $root.SelectLine.bind(this,ItemNo()) "/>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHMhP/).